# How to tell to Search Engines that 2 domain names are the same website?

Tags: asp.net, http, seo

If I have 2 domain names that point to same website (for example: microsoft.com and microsoft.net both point to microsoft.com), how can search engines distinguish that these two websites are the same website and not duplicate content?

My question is because I know that Google, for example, have a duplicate content filter, and I want know what to do to declaratively say that the two domains are the same and are not duplicate content websites.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Choose which is to be the primary domain and then implement a 301 redirect on the other.

Answer (score 3):

Is it important that the user always stays at the domain entered, or are the second merely an alias for the first? If the latter is the case, you could do a HTTP redirect to the desired domainname, when the user visits one of the aliases.

EDIT: Guess Mat beat me to it. :-)

Comment: By about ten seconds, but only because I typed less.

Answer (score 2):

like guys says use 301 header to redirect. but also try to put a robot.txt to deny bots access and avoid have duplicate content

Answer (score 2):

make one site a 301 redirect to the other
but do-not attempt the idiotic idea of a robots.txt
{as for 1 if the secondary site is a 301 to the "real" site a robots.txt couldn't exist as all requests for any content are directed at the primary, that means everything including a robots.txt

thus no duplicate content anywhere all content on one site only
the other just says {your in the wrong place go here instead}

Answer (score 1):

You can establish a permanant forward (301) with most domain hoster.

For subdomains, you can normally have an HttpHandlers that take care of that.